What is the use of C++ feature test macros if they do not exist in C++17 and below?
cppreference says these macros are in the <version> header, which is C++20, but it lists features implemented in previous versions, why? Like, if I want to test for __cpp_lib_is_final in C++20, why would I do that? It is C++20 so I already have is_final!
I do not understand it. So, the feature test macros are not available in pre C++20 versions or no?

I could imagine such defines could be useful in the case of freestanding implementations.

looks like its a legacy from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ciso646

Related/dupe: How do I use the _cpp_lib* feature test macros?

@KenWhite That is not the point of the question. OP means to use those macros from version you need to have C++20, but if you have C++20 you know for sure that it is supported, so there is no need to test. The question is not about how feature testing can be useful in the general case.

You wouldn't "test for __cpp_lib_is_final in C++20".  Only folks who reside in ivory towers can afford to update to the latest/greatest compiler versions and standards.  Real world developers have code that needs to build (and still work!) with older implementations/standards (e.g. must work with C++11 and later, but (nice to have) exploit C++20 features if possible). So, in the real world, you can't simply assume std::is_final (a C++14 feature, BTW) exists. The feature test macros allow testing if the feature exists, using it if present, and coping (coding a work-around) if it isn't.

Also, few compilers have actually implemented all the features of the (then current) standard.   For example, most compilers/libraries that claim to support C++20 actually have some omissions (say, because it takes time to update a compiler and library) in at least a few versions of that compiler.  If you are working with a project that must build with multiple compilers/libraries (and versions!), you will occasionally use a feature that is supported by one compiler but not by another.   Then you will find relevant feature test macros useful.

@WeijunZhou this is exactly my question thank you for somehow understanding my question :)

@Peter I know is_final is a C++14 feature my question was is why is there a feature test macro for it in C++20 when it is a C++14 feature and the only way to check it is via a C++20 feature it does not make sense to me

<version> is the C++20 answer to the question "What is the cheapest include to use if you want a feature macro?". It is not the only way, just a convenient one.

You're wrong in assuming the only way to check for std::final is via a C++20 feature. It's not.  The <version> header just makes life a little simpler if you can assume (or verify) C++20.  If you need to use C++20 features when using a C++20 compiler, but still have code work when built as C++14, then fall back to including the relevant C++14 header (<type_info> in this case) and checking for the macro. In (at a guess) C++2150, the option of #include <type_info> before checking the macro might be deprecated or removed from the standard, and only #include <version> will be needed.

Although the feature-test macros were not part of the standard until C++20, they have lived in https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations since 2015.
Before the introduction of <version>, the recommended way to get a library feature-test macro is to include the relevant header (e.g. <type_traits> for __cpp_lib_is_final).

The use is for compilers that have partial support, ones that support some features and not others.
The feature test macros let you depend on only the features the compiler actually offers.
